# Cast multiple Objects to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections, shopify, liquid

Im looping through some collections *(called categories in Shopify Liquid)*, and I need to cast all those collections into an array, so  I can access their indexes.

What Im doing now is this:

```
{% for link in linklists[page.handle].links limit:1 %}
 {% assign collection = link.object %}

 // Im doing the above code somewhere above in the liquid file, thats where I get the link.object


<script>
  var collections = {{ link.object | json }};
  console.log(collections);
</script>
```

And this is the result I get:

[image]

I need the result to be like this, in an array:
[image]
[image]

How can I cast those set of objects to array like I have shown for the images below?

/********** EDIT *******/

When I use Array.of(), like this:

```
console.log(Array.of(collections));
```

I get this:
[image]

But all those Objects are still not in an array. Maybe push it up one level?

Comment: Probably something like this `Object.values(collections)`

Comment: No, that just turns all the values in an Object to an array. I need all the parent "Object"'s to cast to an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you initiating the collections variable inside the for loop? Try this

```
<script>var collections = new Array</script>
{% for link in linklists[page.handle].links limit:1 %}
 {% assign collection = link.object %}

 // Im doing the above code somewhere above in the liquid file, thats where I get the link.object


<script>
  collections.push({{ link.object | json }});
  console.log(collections);
</script>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you're trying to achieve but have a look at the Array.of method.

```
Array.of({obj1Prop1: 'value1'}, { obj2Prop1: 'value2'});
```

nevertheless - it looks like your collections are actually a collection and you therefore you maybe looking for an array in a higher scope defined and just push / concat them together once you reach your code with your collection.

Comment: Yes, im looking to take all those Objects, and make them into an array: I did what you said and added the Array.of() like this: console.log(Array.of(collections)); Which gave me the result that I provided above on the edit section:

Comment: yes like i said before - use a push into a array defined in a higher scope. @hymnz provided you an example of that.

Answer (score 0):

The object is probably more useful in most cases but you can so something like this:

```
<script>
  var collections = {

    "collections": [{% for collection in collections %}
      {
      {% if collection.image %}"image": "{{ collection.image }}",{% endif %}
      "body_html": "{{ collection.description | url_escape }}",
      "handle": "{{ collection.handle }}",
      "id": {{ collection.id }},
      "sort_order": "{{ collection.default_sort_by }}",
      "template_suffix": "{{ collection.template_suffix }}",
      "title": "{{ collection.title }}",
      "products_count": {{ collection.products_count }},
      "url": "{{ collection.url }}",
      "products": []
      }{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}{% endfor %}
    ]
  }
</script>
```